# Django search bar and capital letters

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django app and I have a question. I have made a search bar. Everything would work correctly as I want but the problem is when the Item has capital letter or vice versa, querying does not work as I would like to. I wanted to make it search for the item when it is written 'tea' or 'TEA' or 'TeA'. I hope you understand me. :)

Code:

```
views.py
  def searchView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        context = request.GET.get('search')
        items = Item.objects.all().filter(title__contains=context)
```

urls.py:

```
     urlpatterns = [
    path('', ShopListView.as_view(), name='home-page'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup-page'),
    path('login', views.loginView, name='login-page'),
    path('logout', views.logoutView, name='logout-page'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', ShopDetailView.as_view(), name='detail-page'),
    path('search/', views.searchView, name='search-page')
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I think here is an issue in querying 'items'. If you want me to paste more code, just write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with the [**`__icontains`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) to make a case-*in*sensitive match:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET

@require_GET
def searchView(request):
    if 'search' in request.GET:
        context = request.GET['search']
        items = Item.objects.filter(title__icontains=context)
    else:
        items = Item.objects.none()
    return render(request, 'shop/search.html', {'items': items})
```

You likely should return something in case the `search` parameter is not passed. For example, an empty page.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to GET requests with the
> [**`@require_GET`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_GET).